# Stripe InvalidRequestError InvalidRequestError at /payment/stripe/ Request req_5yo1v0CwbYGjTV: Must provide source or customer

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to charge a user using stripe in Django. The problem I'm facing is that when I printed my stripeToken value, in the command prompt it is printing "None". That's the reason why I am getting "Invalid Parameters Error". I commented on all the errors, just to see the real error, and it was:

```
InvalidRequestError at /payment/stripe/ Request req_5yo1v0CwbYGjTV: Must provide source or customer.
```

Why is my stripeToken value coming None? Can anyone please help me in solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

My Views.py:

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        the_id = self.request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        print(cart)
        print(order)
        print(token)
        return render(self.request, "orders/payment.html")


    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        the_id = self.request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
        amount = int(order.final_total * 100) # to convert it into cents
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')

        try:
            # user_stripe = self.request.user.userstripe.stripe_id
            # customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user_stripe)
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount= amount, 
                    currency="usd",
                    # card= card,
                    # customer = customer,
                    source = token,
                    description = "Charge for %s" %(self.request.user.username)
                )

            # card = customer.cards.create(card=token)

            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = int(order.final_total())
            payment.save()

            order.payment = payment
            order.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "Your order was successful")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
          # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
          # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.error(self.request, "Rate Limit Error")
            return redirect("/")
        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.warning(self.request, "Invalid Parameters")
            return redirect(".")
        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
          # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
          # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.warning(self.request, "Authentication Error")
            return redirect("/")
        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
          # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.warning(self.request, "API Connection Error")
            return redirect("/")
        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
          # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
          # yourself an email
            messages.error(self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please try again.")
            return redirect("/")
        except Exception as e:
           # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            messages.error(self.request, "A serious error occured. We have been notified.")
            return redirect("/")

        context = {"cart": cart, 'order': order}
        template = "orders/payment.html"
        return render(self.request, template, context)
```

My payment.html :

```
{% block content %}
<div class="current-card-form">
    <form action="." method="post" class="stripe-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="use_default" value="true">
      <div class="stripe-form-row">
        <button id="stripeBtn">Submit Payment</button>
      </div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<script nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The most likely cause of this is a Javascript error that's causing the form-related Javascript to not run, and so your form is posting without having the `token` attribute.

Comment: What can I do now?

Comment: The three print statements return ```Cart id: 61``` ```Order object (11)``` ```None```

Comment: If it prints "None" for the stripeToken  then it didn;t get submitted. Open the develooer console of your browser (on Windows most browsers have F12 as a keyboard shortcut for that), try to submit the form and inspect in the Network tab what is being received and what is being posted. Also check the console if any errors are reported. [edit] your question with your findings.